# Linux Shell in C : chdir() Behaving Odd

Tags: c, linux, shell

first off, this is an assignment for my Operating Systems class.

So, I am writing my own shell in C in Linux. Part of the requirements is to implement the cd command using chdir().

Here is my code snippet:

```
/**
 * The way I parse the user input, argv is a char array which contains
 * the command call and each additional argument is contained in succeeding
 * indices in argv. E.g. 'ls -al' is contained as argv = [ ls | -al ] or
 * 'ssh webserver@server.com -l username' is contained as
 * argv = [ ssh | webserver@server.com | -l | username ]
 */

/* Handle cd */
if (strcmp(argv[0], "cd") == 0){
    struct passwd *pwd;
    char *path = argv[1];

    if(path == NULL){
       pwd = getpwuid(getuid());
       path = pwd->pw_dir;
    }
    /* errno is a previously declared int */
    errno = chdir(path);

    if(errno != 0)
        printf( "Error changing directory!\nError #: %d\nError Descriptor: %s\n", errno, strerror( errno ) );
}
```

What's happening is, when I am in my shell and I cd into a directory (e.g. cd /root/Public/) I successfully change to the directory, chdir() also returns a 0 indicating sucess, however, cd throws the following error:

```
/usr/bin/cd: line 2: cd: /root/Public/: No such file or directory
```

This just baffles me because chdir() was successful and when I type pwd, I am in /root/Public/

Comment: where are you doing the cd call? You are saying the C code works correctly but you are doing an external cd command and it doesn't work?

Comment: The cd call occurs in the chdir() so I am not directly calling cd, but am through a call out to chdir(). The man page is here: [chdir() Man Page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/chdir.2.html)

Comment: We know what `chdir()` does. What are you doing that causes that error message? It's not the error from your shell.

Comment: The error mentions _line 2_. Line 2 of what? That seems to be talking about a script.

Comment: And what is `/usr/bin/cd`?

Comment: I have already answered your question in my post. In my shell I type 'cd /root/Public/'. This calls to the code I list above where chdir() handles the cd. I successfully navigate to /root/Public/ but get the error you see above. The line 2 is not in my code, it's something with cd is all I can gather...

Comment: @Jason: that error is not coming from that piece of code. `chdir` does not (and cannot) call an external `cd` to do its job.

Comment: Where did `/usr/bin/cd` come from?  `cd` is a shell builtin, not a program.

Comment: Not the cause of the issue, but you should not be writing to `errno`. If `chdir` actually fails it will set `errno` and return `-1` but you'll never be able to see the real error code (e.g. for your `strerror` call) because you've stored the `-1` over it. Use a variable of a different name for the `chdir` return value.

Comment: @mafso : I have no clue, this is all in a fresh install of Fedora 20 KDE. I haven't modified anything.

Comment: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/50058/what-is-the-point-of-the-cd-external-command <- for what the external `cd` is. But again, `chdir` does not invoke it.

Comment: What happens *after* that code you excepted above? What do you do after you handle `cd` there? Do you process the input further? Do you perhaps pass it on to the system shell at some point (for 'fall-through' behaviour)?

Comment: Also you really should not test around as `root`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the cause of the issue thanks to Etan Reisner.

The issue was that I wasn't freeing the line after the chdir() call and error handling. So I guess post the chdir() it was picking up some kind of garbage or something? Anyhow, freeing the line resolved the issue.

Also, thanks Andrew Medico, I made the changes as you suggested :)